# How to get the CGI Script response using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cgi

Folks

My scenario : I have a login form. When I click the submit button, it should call a CGI script "someurl?userName=user&password=pwd". Based on the script response, I should be able to forward my pages.

The cgi script response would be,  when entered in browser manually, will display a table if the username and password are correct, else the script will display "Please enter a valid username and password".

Can someone please explain me how to get the CGI script response using AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

```
//serialize your form data
var serializedData = $('form').serialize();


$.ajax({
    url: "...path to your cgi script...",
    type: "post",
    data: serializedData,
    success: function(data) {
      ...data has the response from your cgi script
    }
});
```